# i want output in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
fromdate                 todate

1/5/2017                1/7/2017 

1/5/2017                1/5/2017 

1/5/2017                1/7/2017

1/5/2017                1/7/2017 

1/5/2017                1/6/2017
```

by this syntax:- datediff(day,fromdate,todate)

I want output in this way:-
 0_days     1_days    2_days

1         1           3

Comment: Please clarify, I have not idea what you are trying to do. Also show what you've tried

Comment: what is 1 1 3 in the last line?

Comment: Yes, please add code how You do it

Comment: i want to retrieve subtraction of both(fromdate & todate) & if substraction =0 then create a new column , if substraction =1 then also create a another new column

Comment: 1  1  3 are substraction of both (fromdate & todate) column

Comment: how come it is 1 1 3 when there are 5 entries and the difference is not 1 1 3

Comment: what do you mean create a new column? what column do you want to create ?

Answer (score 0):

use this query

```
select datediff(day, start_date, end_date) as days
from table1;
```

working exmaple [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b9003/3)

above query would give the total days between start_date and end_date